# NTP 4.2.8p15 fails build with glibc 2.34: error: missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: linux, glibc, ntp

I am building NTP 4.2.8p15 with glibc 2.34.
The build fails with error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/pthread.h:33,
                 from work_thread.c:13:
work_thread.c:45:57: error: missing binary operator before token "("
   45 | #if defined(PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) && THREAD_MINSTACKSIZE < PTHREAD_STACK_MIN
      |                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is answered here:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/74690

> Since glibc 2.34 PTHREAD_STACK_MIN is no longer a compile time constant so can not be used in preprocessor comparisons which causes
> the compilation failure [1]. The fix attached to the upstream bug
> report [2] resolves the issue.
>
> Additional info:
>
> - ntp 4.2.8.p15-1
> - https://bugs.ntp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3741
>   [1] ntp-4.2.8.p15-1-x86_64-build.log.xz
>   [2] https://bugs.ntp.org/attachment.cgi?id=1814

To fix this build issue, apply the patch in link to NTP.